# Ejecutar automáticamente powershell al inicio y abrir X pestañas + lanzar sus comandos correspondientes

Tags: python, windows10, powershell

Es posible que, al inicio de sesión de un usuario en win10 se abra automáticamente una ventana de powershell, que a su vez abra 3 pestañas y que en cada una de ellas se ejecute un comando python en concreto?

Tengo 3 scripts independientes entre sí pero que se alimentan mutuamente unos de otros y necesito que en el inicio de sesión del usuario se lancen los 3.

Preferiblemente en una sola ventana de PS con sus 3 pestañas pero si esto es complejo, me serviría tb que se pudiera abrir 3 ventanas distintas de PS y cada una con su comando.

Comment: si se puede solo crea un script que se encargue de eso y muevelo a la carpeta donde se encuentran los programas que se ejecutan al iniciar windows

Comment: También lo podrías poner en el programador de tareas (*taskschd.msc*). Marcas el ejecutable (powershell) y como argumento pones python y la ruta de tus scripts, puede ser 3 tareas por separado así te abre 3 shells. En el desencadenador pones "Al iniciar sesión".

Comment: Gracias a los dos. He estado un buen rato trasteando con powershell, powershell ISE y buscando cómo podía hacerlo de una manera "elegante" pero al final, como siempre, y dado que es para algo mío de ir por casa, me he valido de hacerlo con un script de AutoHotKey que me suele sacar de casi cualquier apuro. Igualmente gracias a ambos, al final he aprendido cositas de ps scripting que no había hecho nunca =)